# Efficiently read a Python sparse matrix from SQL

Tags: python, mysql, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a Table in MySQL with three columns: row-index, column-index and value, which I want to read in into a scipy csr_matrix. I use the Python-MySQL connector. There are 112,500 non-zero elements.

Try 1:

```
A = csr_matrix((N_rows, N_cols), dtype=float)
show = 'SELECT * FROM my_table'
cursor.execute(show)
for (row, col, value) in cursor:
     A[row, col] = value
```

This is too slow, I had to stop it after 60 seconds. It mentioned an efficiency warning, and suggested to use lil matrices.

Try 2:

```
A = lil_matrix((N_rows, N_cols), dtype=float)
show = 'SELECT * FROM my_table'
cursor.execute(show)
for (row, col, value) in cursor:
     A[row, col] = value
A = csr_matrix(A)
```

This takes 6.4 seconds (average of three). Is this as good as it gets, or is there a quicker way in which I can create the csr_matrix without going through a loop? If I perform cursor.fetchall(), the data looks like:

```
[(row_0, col_0, value_0), (row_1, col_1, value_1), ...]
```

This cannot be used for the csr_matrix constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data returned by `cursor.fetchall()` is almost in the [coo_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html) format.
You can do

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

data = cursor.fetchall()
#data = [(1, 2, 1.2), (3, 4, 7.1)]

arr = np.array(data, dtype=[('row', int), ('col', int), ('value', float)])
spmat = coo_matrix((arr['value'], (arr['row'], arr['col'])))
```

Instead of `np.array(cursor.fetchall(), ...)` you could also preferably use

```
arr = np.fromiter(cursor, dtype=[('row', int), ('col', int), ('value', float)])
```

to load the data from the DB directly into the Numpy array.

Comment: Most of the sparse formats accept input in the `(value, (row, col))` style.  The implementation probably first makes a `coo`, and then converts that to `csr` (or what ever).

Comment: Thanks for the hint with coo. Your solution with data=fetchall() and np.array(data,...) brings the read time back to 5.5 seconds. However, the second solution using np.fromiter brings up the read time again, to 6.9 seconds (all averages of 6 times).

Comment: The speed is then probably limited by how fast the Python DB interface can pull out the data from the DB, or even by the speed of the DB engine itself. It might be possible to speed things up if the format the matrix is stored in DB can be changed, e.g. by storing it as raw binary data.

Comment: Unfortunately, now I have upgraded from NumPy 1.8 to NumPy 1.9, the code does not work anymore. Executing the line with `arr = np.array(...)` now gives the following error message: `ValueError: size of tuple must match number of fields.` Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Apparently, the data shall be a list, not a tuple. `data = list(cursor.fetchall())` will do the trick.